# Keep the code in <# #> bracers

Tags: ios, xcode, code-snippets

My problem is pretty simple but I don't know how to solve it. It happens when XCode suggest me an existing function or code snippet. Some places (where I should place my variables) are surrounded by `<#` and `#>` "bracers". It's very usefull function - I can use <kbd>tab</kbd> to move to the next place where I should place my code. But when I have to implement code completion in reactive cocoa:

```
[[signal subscribeError:<#^(NSError *error)errorBlock#> completed:<#^(void)completedBlock#>]
```

I don't know how to remove `<#` and `#>` "bracers" to keep (for the following example) `(NSError *error)errorBlock`.

Comment: Doesn't pressing Enter work?

Comment: Yes! I knew it was really easy problem to solve :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when block is highlighted just press Return key